# Switch Tabs without Reloading Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reload

I have 3 tabs on a page. this tab Switching in Javascript . I have already set first tab is Default Open.. So.. I Click Second Tab is some Text and Submit button..i click the submit button it open the first tab.. i really want to second tab after the submit button.. Please Give me Example for my code. this my code here...

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>

  <form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The default behavior of an input element of type `submit` is do send out a rest request, this will reload the page. If you don't want this behavior you should use a regular button instead of a form input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XMLHttpRequest (Ajax) Request to get data from post form and render data.

```
    window.onload = function() {
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form')).map(function(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var params = "Key1=value1&key2=vakue2";
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        } else {
                            console.log("Error", xhr.statusText);
                        }
                    }
                }
                xhr.open(this.method, this.action, true);
                xhr.send(params);
            });
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because after submitting form page reloads and tabs back to default first tab.

You can handle/submit the form by ajax to prevent page reload. Something like following.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // code for ajax from submission 
})
```

So your full Javascript code should be like following

```
    <script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }

    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

    // Prevent Page Loading and Submit From By Ajax
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form action

        // code for ajax form submission 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you use buttons of type “submit”, a request will be send when you click on it, by default. I’m not sure what exactly you are trying to achive, but there are two ways:

1: change type “submit” to button of type “button”. (Forms data will not be send).

2: stop submit buttons default behaviour, by adding a eventlistener for form “submit” events and then manually handle the requests and flow of your application. For example:

```
const form = document.querySelector(“#yourFormID”)
form.addEventListener(“submit”, function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // this will stop the default behaviour

    // your custom functions here
});
```